# how to change the provider's name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Well i have a website with Omniauth im using devise gem and all works fine but in the Sign_in view i show the providers

```
<%- if devise_mapping.omniauthable? %>
       <%- resource_class.omniauth_providers.each do |provider| %>          
          <%= link_to "#{OmniAuth::Utils.camelize(provider)},", omniauth_authorize_path(resource_name, provider), class: "#{provider} bold" %>  
       <% end -%>
    <% end -%>
```

The problem is because the view Shows:

> Facebook,Twitter,GoogleOauth2

GoogleOauth2 looks very awful, so how can i change the name GoogleOauth2 to "Google" i tried with this but didnt work

```
<%- if devise_mapping.omniauthable? %>
   <%- resource_class.omniauth_providers.each do |provider| %>
      <% provider = "Google" if provider == "GoogleOauth2" %>          
      <%= link_to "#{OmniAuth::Utils.camelize(provider)},", omniauth_authorize_path(resource_name, provider), class: "#{provider} bold" %>  
   <% end -%>
<% end -%>
```

providers:

> devise :omniauthable, omniauth_providers: [:facebook,:twitter,:google_oauth2]

i also tried with this "google_oauth2":

```
<%- if devise_mapping.omniauthable? %>
       <%- resource_class.omniauth_providers.each do |provider| %>
          <% provider = "Google" if provider == "google_oauth2" %>          
          <%= link_to "#{OmniAuth::Utils.camelize(provider)},", omniauth_authorize_path(resource_name, provider), class: "#{provider} bold" %>  
       <% end -%>
    <% end -%>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<% provider = "Google" if provider == "GoogleOauth2" %>
```

This will only modify the value of `provider` if it is `GoogleOauth2`

**Edit:**

Based on comments, what you need is another variable to ***"prettyfy"*** the text shown, but keep the original value to the the `link_to` helper, so this is what I would do:

```
<%= pretty_provider = provider == 'GoogleOauth2' ? "Google": provider %> 
<%= link_to "#{OmniAuth::Utils.camelize(pretty_provider)},", omniauth_authorize_path(resource_name, provider), class: "#{pretty_provider} bold" %>
```

Comment: didnt work brother :( my code: 
<%- if devise_mapping.omniauthable? %>
       <%- resource_class.omniauth_providers.each do |provider| %>
          <% provider = "Google" if provider == "GoogleOauth2" %>          
          <%= link_to "#{OmniAuth::Utils.camelize(provider)},", omniauth_authorize_path(resource_name, provider), class: "#{provider} bold" %>  
       <% end -%>
    <% end -%>

Comment: Update the question with that code (Is hard read code in a comment).

Comment: Are you sure you have a `provider == GoogleOauth2`? no, wait I think I go it. you need another variable.

Comment: Sr im a little noob in stackover can you tell me how?

Comment: Sure @AlienJava, check this link: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235

Comment: thanks a lot Sr. i already do it. can you help me with this issue? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43358469/how-to-show-a-link-to-helper-only-if-it-returns-0 THANKS A LOT

Comment: This is what actually worked for me
`<%= pretty_provider = provider == :google_oauth2 ? :Google : provider %>
<%= link_to "#{OmniAuth::Utils.camelize(pretty_provider)},", omniauth_authorize_path(resource_name, provider), class: "#{pretty_provider} bold" %>  
`

Answer (score 0):

> This is what actually worked for me <%= pretty_provider = provider == :google_oauth2 ? :Google : provider %> <%= link_to "#{OmniAuth::Utils.camelize(pretty_provider)},", omniauth_authorize_path(resource_name, provider), class: "#{pretty_provider} bold" %>

@Gaurav Ragtah

This worked for me as well.

If you're using Hotwire/Turbo in your application, be sure to add `data: { turbo: false }` to the link or button, otherwise Turbo will hijack the request and it will fail.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32215594)