# How to show a link_to helper only if it returns > 0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view-helpers

I have this helper link

```
link_to "", product_path(product, anchor: "disqus_thread"), data: { "disqus-identifier" => "#{url_for([product, {only_path: false}])}" }, class: "no-underline bold grey-text text-darken-3 margin-left"
```

layout: application.rb

```
%script{id: "dsq-count-scr", src: "https://url.disqus.com/count.js", async: "async"}
```

_disqus.html.erb

```
<div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 big-top-space margin-bottom">
  <div id="disqus_thread"></div>
  <script>
    var disqus_shortname = 'yourname';
    var disqus_identifier = '<%= url_for([product, {only_path: false}]) %>';
    var disqus_title = '<%= product.name %>';
    var disqus_url = '<%= url_for([product, {only_path: false}]) %>';
  (function() { // DON'T EDIT BELOW THIS LINE
     var d = document, s = d.createElement('script');
     s.src = 'https://url.disqus.com/embed.js';
     s.setAttribute('data-timestamp', +new Date());
     (d.head || d.body).appendChild(s);
  })();
</script>
<noscript>Please enable JavaScript to view the <a href="https://disqus.com/?ref_noscript">comments powered by Disqus.</a></noscript>

</div>
```

and all works fine I get a number, the number is the disqus comments counter of each post in my index view, but how show only the number if **is greater than 0?** if **is equal to 0** I dont wanna show it in the view. Someone know how to resolve this problem? Thanks a lot

i tried with this:

> add this column to products comment_count       :integer

i changed my _disqus.html

```
 <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 big-top-space margin-bottom">
      <div id="disqus_thread"></div>
      <script>
        var disqus_shortname = 'yourname';
        var disqus_identifier = '<%= url_for([product, {only_path: false}]) %>';
        var disqus_title = '<%= product.name %>';
        var disqus_url = '<%= url_for([product, {only_path: false}]) %>';

       var disqus_config = function () {
    this.callbacks.onNewComment = [
      function() {        
        $.ajax({
          method: "PATCH",
          url: '<%= product_path(product) %>',
          data: {increment: "comment_count"}
        })
      }
    ];
};
      (function() { // DON'T EDIT BELOW THIS LINE
         var d = document, s = d.createElement('script');
         s.src = 'https://url.disqus.com/embed.js';
         s.setAttribute('data-timestamp', +new Date());
         (d.head || d.body).appendChild(s);
      })();
    </script>
    <noscript>Please enable JavaScript to view the <a href="https://disqus.com/?ref_noscript">comments powered by Disqus.</a></noscript>

    </div>
```

Product_controller

```
def update    
    product = Product.find(params[:id])
    product.update(update_product)
  end
def update_product
  params.permit(:comment_count)
end
```

source: https://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/466258-capturing-disqus-commenting-activity-via-callbacks

but i get this error

```
   Started PATCH "/products/12" for ::1 at 2017-04-12 17:44:38 -0500
Processing by ProductsController#update as */*
Parameters: {"increment"=>"comment_count", "id"=>"12"}
ShoppingCart Load (0.0ms) SELECT "shopping_carts".* FROM "shopping_carts" WH
ERE "shopping_carts"."id" = ? LIMIT 1 [["id", 102]]
Product Load (0.0ms) SELECT "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."i
d" = ? LIMIT 1 [["id", 12]]
CACHE (0.0ms) SELECT "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."id" = ?
LIMIT 1 [["id", "12"]]
Unpermitted parameters: increment, id
(0.0ms) begin transaction
User Load (0.0ms) SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT
1 [["id", 1]]
(0.0ms) commit transaction
Rendered products/update.haml within layouts/application (0.0ms)
(0.0ms) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "products" INNER JOIN "in_shopping_carts" ON "p
roducts"."id" = "in_shopping_carts"."product_id" WHERE "in_shopping_carts"."shop
ping_cart_id" = ? [["shopping_cart_id", 102]]
Rendered partials/_unlogged.haml (15.5ms)
Rendered partials/_nav.haml (765.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 3476ms (Views: 3448.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

> Unpermitted parameters: increment, id

in console

> comment_count: nil

someone can help me?

Comment: How do you recover the disqus comments counter? Do you have a Model method?

Comment: i get them with this script in my applicacion.layout %script{id: "dsq-count-scr", src: "https://urlyoururl.disqus.com/count.js", async: "async"}

Comment: I dont recognize that code, please provide more details of that script (on the question).

Comment: i already updated the question Sr.

Comment: I dont see where you get the number, do you save that number in a variable?

Comment: i get the number from the link_to helper bro: documentation here https://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/565624-adding-comment-count-links-to-your-home-page

Comment: Sorry @AlienJava, I dont really understand this tecnology.

Comment: @AlejandroMontilla thanks anyways brother :D all the comunity here is fantastic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way I can think to solve this is to:

- add a `comment_count` attribute to your database
- add a disqus `onNewComment` callback to update the comment count on your record.

With Javascript you can add a callback:

```
var disqus_config = function () {
    this.callbacks.onNewComment = [
      function() {
        alert(comment.id);
        alert(comment.text);
        $.ajax({
          method: "PATCH",
          url: "<%= product_path(product) %>",
          data: {increment: "comment_count"}
        })
      }
    ];
};
```

then you would know the comment count going forward.

documentation: https://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/466258-capturing-disqus-commenting-activity-via-callbacks

Change your Controller to:

```
def update    
  product = Product.find(params[:id])
  if params[:comment_count]
    product.increment!(:comment_count)
  else
    product.update(update_product)
  end
end
```

Comment: i tried with your information brother but didnt work, i already updated my question, what route do i have to write?

Comment: You should run `rake routes` and find the one for updating a product. probably `products_path` with a `patch` Method.

Comment: brother, i did you told me but i get 401 Completed 401 Unauthorized in 391ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms). i already updated my question

Comment: i updated my answer. you should also install https://github.com/rweng/pry-rails#installation to help you learn more about ruby.

Comment: hey guy i could updated the comment_count, but my question is this: in production it isn't a bad idea? because if i have for example 2000 current users same time, and they comment the products same time, for each comment the server updates the comment, it would make slow the platform is true? im not an expert. i hope your opinion teacher

Comment: I marked your answer correct brother thanks a lot. im noob in stackover flow im sorry. well would you be so kind as to answer my question about this method in production. i wanna know if is efficent update a product for each comment. thanks teacher i hope your answer

Answer (score 0):

You can't - at least not in the way you attempting.

```
link_to "", product_path(product, anchor: "disqus_thread"), data: { "disqus-identifier" => "#{url_for([product, {only_path: false}])}" }, class: "no-underline bold grey-text text-darken-3 margin-left"
```

This is evaluated on your Rails server before the page is sent to the browser.

```
<script>
    var disqus_shortname = 'yourname';
    var disqus_identifier = '<%= url_for([product, {only_path: false}]) %>';
    var disqus_title = '<%= product.name %>';
    var disqus_url = '<%= url_for([product, {only_path: false}]) %>';
  (function() { // DON'T EDIT BELOW THIS LINE
     var d = document, s = d.createElement('script');
     s.src = 'https://url.disqus.com/embed.js';
     s.setAttribute('data-timestamp', +new Date());
     (d.head || d.body).appendChild(s);
  })();
</script>
```

This javascript is run later in the client (the users browser) - at that point the page is already sent by the server.

If you want to know when rendering on the server side if there are any comments you need to make a call to the [Disqus API](https://disqus.com/api/docs/) from the server.